# Calculated column based on number of blank columns in a row

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am working on a sharepoint list for task tracking. I'm looking to format a "item completed" column based on completion of previous columns in the table. If any of the three mandatory fields in a row are blank, I'd like the status in the new columns to stat "no". My current formula is listed below. When I go to submit the formula, I receive an error message stating "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported).

I've verified the formula using sample information in Excel and I'm curious if I am missing a nuance for Sharpoint that does not carry over from Excel.

=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Accomplishments (Last 7 Days)],ISBLANK([Focus (Next 7 Days)]),ISBLANK([Status (Overall)]))=1,"No","Yes")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Accomplishments (Last 7 Days)]), "No", IF(ISBLANK([Focus (Next 7 Days)]),"No",IF(ISBLANK([Status (Overall)]),"No","Yes"))
```